# How to represent "range" in python dict

Tags: python

I would like to create dictionary like this:

```
1,2 = "A"

3,4 = "B"

5,6,7・・・(>=5) = "C"
```

so I tried below, but didnt works well..

```
dict = {1:"A", 2:"A", 3:"B", 4:"B", >=5:"C"}
```

how can I create a dictionary like this?

Comment: You can't do that with a dictionary. Your closest structure to that is to make a tuple as the key: `{(1, 2): "A", (3, 4): "B"}`. To represent something like ">=5". You will have to represent it exactly as a string. However, this all seems very hacky and questionable in terms of the design choice. Maybe you can explain what it is you are exactly trying to do? Maybe there is another way you can look at it that will make your design simpler?

Comment: You can't write like that. BTW, can the keys be negative? like `-1, -2`?

Comment: If you have only integers `>0` as key you can define the dictionary without `"C"` and use `your_dict.get(key, "C")`. It will return `"C"` for every key not present.

Comment: I see. Can I describe "C" in this touple?

Comment: @MiyashitaHikaru Can you show an exact sample of the dictionary you are looking to create?

Comment: sorry, I couldnt read everything. my goal is to replace dataframe. so maybe I have to replace >=5 as C first, then replace with dict ...?

Comment: One possible way to deal with this kind of question is to use an approach suggested by @idjaw in a slightly different way. You can use tuple like this: `(minVal, maxVal): '<grade>'`. From the question: `{ (1, 2):'A', (3,4):'B', (5,-1): 'C' }`. So with this approach, whenever you want to assign a `grade` to a `new_value`, just check if the `new_value` lies between any particular tuple. If so, assign that `grade`. I am assuming that `-1` never occurs as `new_value`. You may also use `None` as well.

Comment: Use class instead of dictionary

Comment: Expanding on the idea of @KlausD., you could also define your dictionary as a `collections.defaultdict`, and use `lambda: "C"` as `default_factory`. This will then be useable transparently like a `dict`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lookup of a value where the key is in a sorted range is capped at `O(log n)`. Hence using a dictionary directly is not viable. You can either do this by:

- storing the ranges in list, sorting them, and doing a binary search, or...
- using a tree data structure.

There are other creative solutions such as storing all the numbers in the range in the dictionary as integer keys and have duplicate references to the same value (which looks like what you have above). This would be `O(1)` lookup, but would have the negative side effects such as:

- cannot modify the ranges easily without updating all the keys
- wasted space for large ranges
- cannot do lookups with floats

...which might be okay depending on your use case.

In summary, there is no direct solution.

Comment: For lots of data, an Interval tree would be fitting. If the data is small like the literal question, an if/elif/.../else sequence would be a fine solution.